# xhr.responseXML is different result in Chrome and IE

Tags: javascript, xml, xmlhttprequest

I have a strange problem.

I want to load a XML file through `XMLHttpRequest()` and access it.
I can get correct XML document in Chrome and Firefox but something wrong in IE.

I had set breakpoints and printed out `xhr.responseXML` and found out the result was not native document structure in IE.

**Chrome:**

```
#document
   <CONFIG>
   ....
   </CONFIG>
```

**IE:**

```
[object XMLDocument]{activeElement: undefined, alinkColor: "#0000ff", all: undefined, anchors: HTMLCollection {...}, applets: HTMLCollection {...}, ATTRIBUTE_NODE: 2, attributes: null, bgColor: "#ffffff", body: null, CDATA_SECTION_NODE: 4, characterSet: "utf-8", charset: "utf-8", childNodes: NodeList {...}, COMMENT_NODE: 8, compatible: MSCompatibleInfoCollection {...}, compatMode: "CSS1Compat", constructor: XMLDocument {...}, cookie: "", defaultCharset: "big5", defaultView: null, designMode: "inherit" ...}
```

How cant I fix this issue?

Thanks

**UPDATE:**

```
var xmlData = {};

function loadXMLFile(file, cb) {
  var xmlDoc = {};
  if (window.ActiveObject) {
      xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
      xmlDoc.async = true;
      xmlDoc.load(file);
      xmlData = xmlDoc;
      cb();
  } else if (document.implementation && document.implementation.createDocument) {
      var xhr= new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.open("GET", file, true);

      xhr.responseType = 'document';
      xhr.overrideMimeType('text/xml');

      xhr.onload = function () {
          if (xhr.readyState === xhr.DONE) {
              if (xhr.status === 200) {
                  console.log(xhr.responseXML);   // reponseXML is different in Chrome and IE
                  xmlDoc = xhr.responseXML;
                  xmlData = xmlDoc;
                  cb();
              }
          }
      };

      xhr.send(null);
  } else {
      console.log('not support javascript');
  }
}

function checkExist(name) {
  var link = xmlData.getElementById(name).getElementsByTagName('url')[0].innerHTML;  // IE appear ERROR here
  // SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'getElementsByTagName' of undefined or null reference


  var ele = document.getElementsByClassName(name);

  // do somthing...

}

window.onload = function() {
    loadXMLFile(file, function() {
      checkExist("ID");
      checkExist("NAME");
    });
}
```

Comment: `reponseXML is different in Chrome and IE` - how it's shown on the console is irrelevant - does it work otherwise? in other words, do you get errors in the console?

Comment: I have updated my code. It works without errors in Chrome but IE has an error. The error appears when I enter callback function. The console showns `Unable to get property getElementsByTagName ...`

Answer (score 0):

I seem to find the problem. After I loaded the XML file, I used `xmlData.getElementById(name)` and this is the problem.

The `getElementById()` method is not assure to access the DOM. In other words, it might not work in specific browsers.

At the end, I accessed the XML file through jquery instead of pure javascript.